# Swap string field values in Groovy with inline regex?

Tags: regex, string, groovy, replace

I have a POJO:

```
public class Dog {
    String uuid;

    // ...etc.
}
```

I would like to write a simple Groovy expression that replaces instances of certain characters in the `uuid` string field with other chars/strings, specifically:

- Replace instances of "`@`" with the word "`elbow`"
- Replace instances of double-quote "`"`" with a single-quote ("`'`")
- Replace instances of "`%`" with the word "`shoulder`"

I know the Groovy will be something like:

```
myDog.getUUID().replaceAll("[@|\"|%]+", ???);
```

But I can't figure out how to do all 3 inline, as well as what their actual regexes should be.

If possible I'd like it to be one single `replace` command and not 3 separate ones, but if a single command isn't possible I'll take 3 individual replaces. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain `replace` methods together

```
uuid = uuid.replace("@", "elbow").replace("\"", "'").replace("%", "shoulder");
```

Answer (score 2):

Usign map + regular expression:

```
subs = [
    '@': 'elbow',
    '"': "'",
    '%': 'shoulder'
]
uuid = 'a @ b % c " d';
uuid.replaceAll(/[@"%]/, { subs[it[0]] })
// ===> a elbow b shoulder c ' d
```

**NOTE**

- You don't need `|` inside `[]`. If exists, `|` is also matched.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use regex for that: do:

```
string str = dog.uuid.replace("@", "elbow");
str = str.replace("%", "shoulder");
str = str.replace("%", "shoulder");
str = str.replace("\"", "\'");
dog.uuid = str;
```

we are using the format `"\""` so the compiler won't confuse between a quates in string and a string's bounds